# Getting the value from form MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This the simple question but i don't know how to over come this issue
      I have design the webpage which get the data from the database and we can able to edit the data. But if i submit the button for save what ever i have edited  it does not getting the value in the parameter.

image reference
[image]

And this is my controller

```
 public ActionResult Movielist()
    {
        var movie = _context.MovieviewTable.ToList();
        ViewBag.movielist = movie;

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult tabelForm()
    {
        var dropdown = _context.MovieviewTable.ToList();
        var viewmodel = new MovieViewModel
        {
            MovieDropdownCollection=dropdown
        };

        return View(viewmodel);
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var refelect = _context.MovieviewTable.SingleOrDefault(c => c.id == id);
        var viewmodel = new MovieViewModel
        {
            movieView = refelect,
            MovieDropdownCollection = _context.MovieviewTable.ToList()
    };
        return View("tabelForm", viewmodel);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Submitform(MovieView movie)
    {
        //if(movieViewModel.Movieviewdatacollection.id==0)
        //{
        //    _context.MovieviewTable.Add();
        //}

        return View();
    }
```

And this is my viewmodel

```
public IEnumerable<MovieView> MovieDropdownCollection
    {
        get;set;
    }
    public MovieView movieView
    {
        get;set;
    }
```

And this is my View

```
@model Practiceupdateedit.ViewModel.MovieViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "tabelForm";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>tabelForm</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Submitform", "Movie"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.movieView.MovieName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.movieView.MovieName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.movieView.AddedOn)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.movieView.AddedOn, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.movieView.Genere)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.movieView.Genere,new SelectList(Model.MovieDropdownCollection,"Genere","Genere"), new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.movieView.Instock)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.movieView.Instock, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

Can someone plz help me really i have spend to-much of time

Comment: View models do NOT contain data models. Refer [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Comment: And your view is based on `MovieViewModel` therefore the parameter in the POST method also needs to be `MovieViewModel`, not `MovieView`

Comment: ya correct but if add the `MovieviewModel` it showing error at while adding movie ` _context.MovieviewTable.Add(movie);` and my `MovieViewTable` is my dbset @StephenMuecke

Comment: Read the link I gave you. You get the data model from the db and map the view model properties to it, then save the data model

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke if i use movieviewmodel  then it showing cannot convert viewmodel to model while add `_context.MovieviewTable.Add(movie)` any solution is there for this?

Comment: READ THE LINK I GAVE YOU!!!

Answer (score 0):

you are using 2 different model MovieViewModel while passing to the view and while submiting you are using movieView

Change:

```
public ActionResult Submitform(MovieView movie)
```

To:

```
public ActionResult Submitform(MovieViewModel movie)
```

Comment: if i use movieviewmodel i throwing error like cannot convert from viewmodel.movieviewmodel to models.moviewview if(movieViewModel.Movieviewdatacollection.id==0)
        {
            _context.MovieviewTable.Add();
        }

Comment: I think so ou should be able to

Comment: @Aeijit Mukherjee if i use movieviewmodel it throwing error like cannot convert from viewmodel.movieviewmodel to models.moviewview if(movieViewModel.Movieviewdatacollection.id==0) { _context.MovieviewTable.Add(); }  while adding in context.movieviewtable.add(movie)